# Laravel Escape quotes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using laravel 4.2 and I am having a very weird problem while saving the data using the model.
I have a text area where user inputs some text and then hit the save button. it is saving fine when the text does not have any quotes in it. But gives issues when the text have some quotes.
For example: If I try to save `"Hi. I am Jacky's friend."` This text saves fine but when I check in the database there I see this `"Hi. I am Jacky\\\'s friend."` I get extra back slashes saved in the database.

This is my code :

Suppose $textnotes is the variables in which I am getting the entire text.

```
$savenotes = new Details(); // Details is the model and the table name is 'Details'
$savenotes->Notes = $textnotes; // 'Notes' is the column
$savenotes->save();
if(!empty($savenotes->id))
 // My other stuffs here
```

I am unable to fix this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: any found solutions?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a PHP setting called Magic Quotes interfering with strings when they contain certain characters, rather than a Laravel specific problem. You can turn this off in your php.ini file, by following instructions [in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).

Comment: I have a very similar issue, and we are using `"illuminate/database": "~5.4.0"` and PHP 7.0. According to documentation, this setting (`magic_quotes_runtime`, `magic_quotes_gpc`) has been removed since PHP 5.4.